# stdin.write throws Error: write EPIPE

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm getting this error when openssl child proccess is trying to write() to local directory.
Connection is closed before write() is called. It isn't connected with the ssl, because I can't even launch example code from nodejs documentation.

What am I missing? Some kind of special rights for nodejs?

Please, can anyone give me a real example how to use childProccess.stdin.write()?

```
events.js:85
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^
Error: write EPIPE
at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:690:26)
at Socket._write (net.js:709:8)
at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:301:12)
at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:288:5)
at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:217:11)
at Socket.write (net.js:634:40)
at signManifest (...\node_modules\passbook\lib\pass.js:360:14)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared that i've installed openssl in a wrong way. An error (wrong openssl directory) while execFile(openssl) emitted 'close' event, so write threw EPIPE.

Be careful and add a lot of proper error handlers :)